# Low beam headlights failing every 3-4 weeks

Tags: electrical, volvo

I have Volvo XC90 2006 and for the past few months every 3 - 4 weeks changing low beam light. Last time even did not last 5 days. Any recommendations why this light is failing?

Answer (score 5):

The most common reason for this is getting skin oil onto the bulb during changing of the bulb. This will kill most every bulb on the market today. This creates hot spots on the bulb which will cause the filaments to burn out at an accelerated rate.

If you aren't already, use clean, new, nitrile gloves to keep the oil off. If you don't have nitrile gloves, you can utilize a paper towel to hold the bulb while putting it into the socket.

Any kind of contaminants on the bulb will cause the same problem. If there is any kind of leakage getting into your headlight housing, it too can cause problems with your new bulbs. Mainly, if you see condensation on the inside of the housing, it could be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Another surprisingly common problem is water in the headlight lenses (ie uin the unit iteslf), especially after heavy rainfall. It forms a puddle at the bottom of the unit until maybe you hit a bump or brake hard, then splashes up & hits the bulb itself .. zap! temperature difference upsets the bulb.

Have a close look at the light units from the outside and see if you can see any water collected at the bottm. might help to wobble the car about a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're replacing the new bulb using clean cotton gloves (as you should be!), then you issue is usually due to a failing connector. You need to replace the connector. A failing connector can also overheat some of the wiring harness adjacent to it, so you'll most likely need to cut it out and splice in a replacement. Auto parts stores offer connectors with attached wire pigtails that are suitable for such a repair.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with touching the bulbs. There is a known issue with Volvo headlights burning out prematurely. Unfortunately, very common. Google is your friend.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do you have any references beyond your statement which explains this?